# Wordpress - User controlled sorting/filtering

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I've been trying to find a solution to this, but haven't had a whole lot of luck.

I need to give the user control over which posts are being displayed on the homepage via selectboxes. Essentialy, a 'filter by' (list of categories) and a 'sort by' (date, name and a few other custom fields).

Is there anyway to do this and have the loop refresh dynamically?

Thanks!

Z

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: To be honest, I'm kind of going from nothing. I've done a lot of wordpress builds, but have never really run into this. Not even sure where to start.

Comment: You should have a look at AJAX. Add the select-boxes and at "change"-Event you fetch+update the contents of the select-boxes. Afterwards, when all is selected, you make an ajax-call to a php-service that returns the blog posts, sorted, in json format. You then update your blog posts.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, makes sense. Posted a link to a pretty good tutorial below if anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a non-coding way to do it you could use the Types & Views plugin: http://wp-types.com/

Otherwise you'll need to use javascript or jQuery to trigger an update after the user selects the categories and other criteria. Something like a submit button that triggers an ajax post of the criteria selected which then retrieves the requested posts and updates the page content.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense.

Found this article which should help anyone else coming across this issue: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/